# Converting to Parcel Fabric - Extra lines, verticies, and the clean up process

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, parcel-fabric

I am currently taking my first stab at trying to convert our City's parcel layer into a parcel fabric.  From what I understand, our DWG is converted to vector and ArcGIS processes.  It does not come in as a coverage or shape.  A lot of the linework was done years ago, and not much of it has been redrawn within AutoCAD.  I'm trying to clean up 717k objects...

The first step I did was convert the polygons to lines.  Using a series of tools (generalize and lines and curves) I'm slowly cleaning up the line work.  I've zoomed into approximately a 1 sq mi. region, run the tools, fix any errors manually that it cannot fix, such as arcs displayed at jagged lines.  When I have no errors, I continue.

After reading about splitting polylines and checking curves in the staging process, it says that parcel lines must be two point lines or curves representing a single boundary.  I've reduced lines with extra vertices where needed, but after running the tools listed above, I'm left with a lot of multiple 2 vertex lines (end point/end point) which make up a boundary (see photo).

Is this acceptable for the fabric?

Will I generate errors still?

[image]

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.